# pdf reader is reading only first 2 pages but not all the pages of PDF file in obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, pdf-reader

i have downloaded this[Example code](https://github.com/iamruinous/Reader) its a  pdf reader code, its having a pdf of only 2 pages,,now i have changed the pdf with a larger pdf which contains 12 pages  and i executed the code but still its displaying first 2 pages,,actually they are calculating no of pages based on the pdf file itself  but i dont know y i am not getting all pages which are in the new PDF file

can any buddy help me out,,, can u suggest similar example codes,, thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code: http://www.vfr.org/2011/07/pdf-reader-viewer-v2-0/ , it is an open source PDF viewer for iOS.